# check if there update or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

the web page update database but if I didn't write any thing he make delete  the data in database how can I check if there is update in the code or not

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext sdc = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {      
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
        byte[] fileByte = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        Binary binaryObj = new Binary(fileByte);
        Professor_Dim prof = sdc.Professor_Dims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.P_ID == 0);
        prof.P_Fname = txtfirstname.Text;
        prof.P_Lname = txtlastname.Text;
        prof.P_Email = txtemail.Text;
        prof.P_Address = txtaddress.Text;
        prof.P_Phone = txtphone.Text;
        prof.P_Image = binaryObj;
        sdc.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to do. Can you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext sdc = new DataClasses1DataContext()) 
    {      
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
        byte[] fileByte = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        Binary binaryObj = new Binary(fileByte);
        Professor_Dim prof = sdc.Professor_Dims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.P_ID == 0);

        if (  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfirstname.Text))
            prof.P_Fname = txtfirstname.Text;

        if (  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtlastname.Text))
            prof.P_Lname = txtlastname.Text;

        if (  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtemail.Text))
            prof.P_Email = txtemail.Text;

        if (  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtaddress.Text))
            prof.P_Address = txtaddress.Text;

        if (  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtphone.Text))
            prof.P_Phone = txtphone.Text;

        prof.P_Image = binaryObj;
        sdc.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to mark as an answer if this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to use GetChangeSet()

```
ChangeSet cs = sdc.GetChangeSet();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset(v=vs.110).aspx

This will give you an object with three members, a list of changed rows, a list of deleted rows, and a list of inserted rows.

Comment: sorry but how to insert this in my code

Comment: I don't understand your question -- are you asking how to use a text editor?

Comment: how to check if the is text in textbox or not

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShalata that is a different quesiton -- you should post another question about how you don't know what the `.Text` property is and how to use it.